# htaccess domain redirect including subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to a new domain and include subdomains...

For example http://somesub.olddomain.com/someuri should redirect to http://somesub.newdomain.com/someuri

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `.htaccess` on your old subdomain domain like:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://somsub.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or, for all subdomains of a particular domain, the rule would be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.){0,1}olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://{%1}newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No problem! ^^ Glad it worked!